# Return value from function React from an Axios' response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have this function in React that should export the result got from an Axios' API call:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function youtube(channelId) {

    var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=${channelId}&key=AIzaxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`,
    headers: { }
    };

    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount)
        return response.data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return 0
    });
    

}
```

Problem: it returns undefined. But the console.log displays the correct data.

Comment: Not possible, you are doing something wrong

Comment: Here is the working example of it https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-cherry-dqu40?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The main difference is that in the function I do an external API call with axios: axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
console.log(response.data)
    return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    return 0
    });
--------
console.log here works, but not the returned value

Comment: You are accessing the promise here, for asynchronous tasks you need to resolve it for return any value or use async/await for better reading purpose

Comment: Updated the request with more details. The problem is that I can't put the return there... ideas?

Comment: Please check the updated code sandbox link

Answer (score 1):

In a `Synchronous` way that is not possible but yes in an `asynchronous` way, it's possible, As per our comment discussion, you are accessing the `promise` and for `asynchronous` tasks, you need to `resolve` it to `return` any value or use `async/await` for better reading purposes.

In your code, the problem is you are `returning` in `then/catch`, another `then/catch` will be waiting for your input, it will not succeed until you will not `settled` the promise.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-cherry-dqu40?file=/src/App.js